# how to verify activity was launched in Android

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-activity

I have a screen with multiple buttons that launch different activities. I need to create unit tests that verify that a particular button launches the appropriate activity. I know I can test manually, but I want to create automated unit tests.

When I start an activity like this:

startActivity(new Intent(this, MyClass.class));

Is there a way to verify programmatically (in unit tests) that MyClass activity was launched?

Comment: Never saw that call failing... it should throw a exception in that case.

Comment: Why would you need such a test?

Comment: Did you figure this out?  I have a similar use case - I need to verify that System Settings Activity gets launched from my app.